# How to convert day/month/year date to .NET style 100ns ticks since Jan 1, 0001?

Tags: .net, c, date, time, embedded

I am working on an embedded project and need to convert a DDMMYY date and HHMMSSmmm time to a .NET style [100ns ticks since Jan 1, 0001.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

I have the values broken out into year, month, day, hour, second, minutes, milliseconds, like so:

```
//DDMMYY
year = Date.Val % 100 + 2000;//Year
month = (Date.Val / 100) % 100;//JAN = 1, FEB = 2, etc
day = (Date.Val / 10000) % 100;//day of the month
//HHMMSSmmm
millisecond =   (UTCTime.Val % 1000);
second =        (UTCTime.Val / 1000) % 100;
minute =        (UTCTime.Val / 100000) % 100;
hour =          (UTCTime.Val / 10000000) % 100;
```

What I need now is a way to take these values and do the embedded C equivalent of this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 4, 7, 7, 5, 23, 205);
long ticks1 = date.Ticks;
```

*Edit*
I'm working on a PIC32 microcontroller.

Comment: There's a Win32 function called [`SystemTimeToFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948(v=vs.85).aspx) which will do this for you (except for adding a constant). Do you have that available?

Comment: I am working on a PIC32MX, so no.  I should add that info though.

Answer (score 3):

Use the POSIX-specified formula for seconds since the *correct* epoch, then adjust it for the number of seconds between the correct epoch and the ".NET epoch", scale, and add on the 100-ns-tick component.

```
 tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
    (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
    ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
```

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15

Comment: I don't have day of the year, I have day of the month.  Makes this solution a little inconvenient but still functional.

Comment: Isn't converting day of month to day of year a typical introductory programming exercise? Or did that go out of fashion in the 90s? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it with just standard C by using [mktime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime).  First, put your values into a `struct tm`:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

You can ignore wday and yday, but should set isdst to -1 (read the man page for details).  Then, call `mktime()` which will give you the seconds since 1970.  Then, using whatever means necessary, such as a trivial one-off C# program, figure out the seconds between the Microsoft epoch and the Unix one.  This is an immutable value which you should hard-code into your C program.  Add that to the result of mktime, multiply to convert seconds to ticks, and add in your milliseconds part.

Comment: `mktime` is problematic because it works in local time, not universal time.

Comment: I'm working on a PIC, will that even notice the difference?  Will test this tomorrow to check, but I'd guess that it wouldn't have any way to know what timezone it was in.